# Попасть на диск С в cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

Объясните, пожалуйста, как попасть на диск C в cmd. При обычной команде `C:` выдает `User\Administrator` а нужно просто `C:`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `help` -- увидишь много команд, и `cd` -- самая часто используемая. Можно так `cd ../..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто можно выполнить две команды

```
C: && cd \
```

Answer (score 8):

Вы и так на диске `C:`. Нужно сменить текущую директорию с помощью команды `cd` (change directory):

```
cd C:\
```

(перейти в корень диска `C:`)

или

```
cd \
```

(перейти в корень текущего диска)

Если нужно перейти из директории на другом диске в корень диска C:, то нужно добавить ключ `/D`:

```
cd /D C:\
```

это аналогично двум командам: `C:`, потом `cd C:\`